# Is there a workaround to python (django) model ordering and references

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the code below, TimePeriod must be declared after Day.  Similarly, TimePeriod cannot be referenced in the Day method 'get_all_time_periods'.

Is there a workaround to this restriction (also what is this ordering restriction called for further googling)?

I have a much more complex scenario with many classes referencing Day and I would like to write a method in Day to collect all these models.  However, Day must be declared before all the classes which reference it.  What's best practice in these scenarios?  It seems wrong to write this in the view, and I don't like the idea of creating a utility method for this purpose.

Thanks in advance,

## models.py

```
class Day(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    
    def get_all_time_periods(self):
        pass
        #can't reference time period here


class TimePeriod(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the model name as a string to `models.ForeignKey`:

```
class TimePeriod(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey("Day", null=True, blank=True)
```

Then there is no need to define `class Day` before you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

akxlr answer is right, just use `models.ForeignKey("another_model", null=True, blank=True)`

but when you have really complex models and need to add a methods like your **get_all_time_periods** you can use this:

```
Day.get_all_time_periods = property(lambda self: filter(lambda t: self == t.day, TimePeriod.objects.all()))
```

you can customize this property to get your right data, it is just an example